# getting error /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: python, shell, unix

I want to run the following script from python:

```
temp=$(sky2xy image.fits 124.6456 -2.5517); arr=(${temp// / });
```

For that I am using the `os.system()` module:

```
import os
os.system('temp=$(sky2xy image.fits 124.6456 -2.5517); arr=(${temp// / });')
```

But I am getting an unexpected syntax error

> sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>   512

The error is due to the parenthesis used in `arr=(${temp// / })`

How should I get rid of this error?

Comment: You're trying to do bash-specific stuff using `sh`. This is almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: I would suggest that you do the minimum amount of work in the shell (i.e. `sky2xy image.fits 124.6456 -2.5517`), save the result in python and manipulate it from there.

Comment: I am actually trying to use Image magick, hence I am using the commandline. The complete script is as follows  temp=$(sky2xy img.fits 124.6456 -2.5517); arr=(${temp// / }); X=${arr[4]};Y=${arr[5]}; convert -quiet img.fits -level 7.26470947266%,7.85173086528% -negate -fill transparent -stroke red -draw "circle $X,$Y `echo $X+5|bc`,$Y" -stroke black -draw "rectangle `echo $X-12|bc`,`echo $Y-12|bc` `echo $X+12|bc`,`echo $Y+12|bc`" -crop 50x50+`echo $X-25|bc`+`echo $Y-25|bc`\! -background transparent -flatten +repage img2.png;

Comment: Fair enough, in that case I would suggest taking a look at one of the [python APIs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) mentioned here.

Comment: By the way, you should [edit] your question to add further detail, rather than using the comments.

Comment: What's the point of replacing space with space? `${temp// / }`?

Answer (score 1):

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected 512
^^^
```

`/bin/sh` is not the same as `/bin/bash` (or `/usr/bin/bash`, as the case may be). You are attempting to use Bash-specific syntax in a shell that doesn't understand it.